# WP_Query searching by tag

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am in the process of setting up WordPress with WooCommerce, one of the requirements is a bit of integration that takes a person from another website directly to a specific product. I have set the external product references on tags in the products

an example incoming query would be:

```
http://localhost/TestSite/search?q=9404
```

I have written a short plugin that does this, but **I can't seem to get it to search products by tag**.

You can see the two lines of $params for example, the top one (currently commented out) works fine when searching by product id, but the bottom one trying to work from tag produces nothing. Can you see where I am going wrong?

P.S. This is my first attempt at a wordpress plugin. it is potentially inefficient, security compromising or has some glaring issue. I am going to submit it to stack overflow code review, but I need to get this one last bug ironed out!

Thanks for any help you can offer. Also, if you can suggest an alternative method to getting from a tag to a product URL I will interested.

```
//Test Product Id: 11030
//Tag on Test Product: 9404
//http://localhost/TestSite/search?q=9404

function TagLinker() {

    if (isset($_GET['q']))
    {
        $TagNumber = $_GET['q'];

        //create the params array
        //$params = array('post_type' => 'product', 'p' => 11030);
        $params = array('post_type' => 'product', 'tag' => $TagNumber);

        $wc_query = new WP_Query($params);

        if ($wc_query -> have_posts() ) {
            $wc_query -> the_post();

            $product_id = get_the_ID();

            $url = get_permalink( $product_id );

            wp_reset_postdata();

            if ( wp_redirect( $url ) ) {exit;}
        };
    }

}

add_action( 'init', 'TagLinker' );
```

Comment: Is `9404` really the tag (i.e. a string) or is it maybe the `tag_id`? In the latter case you'd have to use `'tag_id' => $TagNumber` in the parameters array.

Comment: Yep, that is the string text of the tag, the tag "slug" i think its called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
function TagLinker(){

    if (isset($_GET['q']))
    {
        $TagNumber = $_GET['q'];
        $params=array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => array( array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $TagNumber
                        )
        ));
        $wc_query = new WP_Query($params);

        if ($wc_query -> have_posts() ) {
            $wc_query -> the_post();

            $product_id = get_the_ID($wc_query->ID);

            $url = get_permalink( $product_id );

            echo $url;
            //wp_reset_postdata();
            //if ( wp_redirect( $url ) ) {exit;}
        };
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'TagLinker' );
```

Comment: Great stuff, thanks. I will check that out next chance I get!

Comment: thansk for your help, but this one has not worked. Which is strange, because you have clearly tested it. It is not bringing back any records at all. Is there some extra plugin I need to install? I am running on a plain up to date version of wordpress and the latest version of woocommerce. Thanks for any extra help you can offer!

Comment: changed the search field from 'id' to 'slug' working like a dream now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$params=array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => array( array(
                            'tag' => $TagNumber
                        ),
        ));
```

You should give the tag in array. Kindly refer tag section in the developer page . https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try later in the week.

Comment: This one has not worked sorry. it seems to bring back everything and return the first item in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

```
$params = array(
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $TagNumber,//this is category slug da mani
        )
    )
);
```

try this code. It was working in my machine.